# Symfony: "Array to string conversion" error on Roles management

Tags: symfony, security, roles

I've started exploring security on Symfony 4.4.7. User creation works and I can see its params saved on DB:

```
MariaDB [(symfony)]> desc user;
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username | varchar(180) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| roles    | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.106 sec)

MariaDB [symfony]> select * from user;
+----+---------------+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | username      | roles         | password                                                                                          |
+----+---------------+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 13 | administrator | ["ROLE_USER"] | $argon2id$v=19$m=65536,t=4,p=1$rDxNxYso7afyYiTaTnuL9A$kW+fMWykrEUHVzPMFvZSvPwENohmKakk9iymvJRhu98 |
+----+---------------+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

But when I try to login I get an error: "Notice: Array to string conversion"
Error points to this line of code:         return array_unique($roles);

On log I have:

```
[2020-05-28 10:28:44] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception ErrorException: "Notice: Array to string conversion" at /var/www/symfony/src/Entity/User.php line 68 {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Notice: Array to string conversion at /var/www/symfony/src/Entity/User.php:68)"} []
```

What is wrong here?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Normally `roles` field store in database like serialized array. In your case it should be `a:1:{i:0;s:9:"ROLE_USER";}`.